# Variable sized wrap layout in WP 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am building my Windows Phone 8 application in c#. I am supposed to have layout like the below layout in my app.

[image]

Basically i load the layout elements in ListBox. Order of the arrangements are like Item1, Item4, Item2.. etc.Toolkit's WrapPanel did not help to achieve this layout. Anyone can you give me the idea of doing the below layout in my app ?

Comment: Just to confirm, your list contains the items in the order Item 1/Item 2/Item 4? So after positioning Item 2, you  need to detect there's an available space in the top right corner to put Item 4? If so, I don't believe any built-in panel can achieve such behavior. You'll have either to make your own panel (that can be tricky), or it's probably more realistic to pre-process your list and re-order the elements to have Item 1/Item 4/Item 2, then use a classical WrapPanel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable sized wrap grid control available in the Kinnara wp toolkit... maybe it can help?
You can get it at [github here...](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit)

Answer (score -1):

You can make thing like this :

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">Item 1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Item 2</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Item 3</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: As i told clearly in the question. I load all the elements in the ListBox. So i need like Panel to arrange the elements through ItemsPanel.

Comment: what is the problem to make this in item template?

Comment: I bind the ItemsSource to the ListBox.